# VBA count value of the same column in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate a sequential no in a timesheet that marked with activity. Each worksheet represent a month. If i mark an activity on jan 12, jan 12 will get a ref no like 20190402000001, and if i mark another activity on feb 13, then another ref no 20190402000002 will be generated next to feb 13 in february worksheet.

The ref no will not be reused if the activity is cancelled on the same day.

My thought is to count the no of prefix =today (eg 20190402) in the same column across all worksheets and assign the sequential no.

But I have two questions.

1. how I could record the last used ref no? For example, if the latest activity 20190402000005 is cancelled and another activity is added, how could i program such that the ref no 20190402000006 should be assigned?
2. How to count the ref no on the same columns across the worksheets?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could do something like `x = DateCode00001` then if x exists, `x = x + 1` until you have a unique value...

Comment: @Chrismas007 but this cannot handle the scenario that I delete the latest activity and then create another one. Eg I delete the latest activity with ref code 20190402000005.. then the activity created afterwards should be 20190402000006

Comment: Does the reference number reset with a new day @George ?

Comment: @Chrismas007 yes, the prefix is today in format yyyymmdd

Comment: @George can you have a "holding cell" that you don't use?

Comment: @Chrismas007 I prefer not to... or is it possible to have one counter in backend?

Comment: @George VBA doesn't store variables when you close the doc so yes you'd have to have a holding cell.

Comment: Now I understand,. You want an autoincrement field ID like databases have. Easy solution is exactly what @Chrismas007 suggests: Store the last used ID in a cell (you can hide that worksheet, anyways). Hardcore solution would be using VBA to store the last used ID in code itself, and use VBA to updating the code all the time (not recomended).